# Dificuldade em escolher a função Strings correta

Tags: php

Estou com um exercício para resolver e estou com alguma dificuldade.

Esse é o enunciado do problema:

Imprima novamente os nomes dos alunos por ordem de matrícula, mas somente daqueles cuja letra inicial seja diferente de “T”.

Esse é meu código.

```
$nomes = array('andre' => 1 , 'paulo' =>5, 'fabio' => 2,'tiago' => 4);
asort($nomes);
foreach ($nomes as $key => $value) {
  echo
```

Li o manual do PHP e verifiquei as diversas funções para string. Tentei até algumas delas como `count_chars()`, `str_word_count`, sem sucesso. Alguém pode dar uma ajuda e me explicar se possível aonde estou cometendo o erro e qual seria a função correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cada interação de seu laço foreach a variavel **$key** recebera o valor do índice do seu array e a variável **$valor** recebera o valor contido. Logo em seguida é preciso verificar a primeira letra de cada palavra fornecida como índice de seu array, para isso utilizamos a variável **$key** e a função **strcasecmp**  nativa do php, que faz a comparação de strings sem diferenciar letras maiúsculas ou minusculas.

```
<?php
      $ord_nomes = array();
      $nomes     = array('andre' => 1 , 'paulo' =>5, 'fabio' => 2,'tiago' => 
      asort($nomes);
      foreach ($nomes as $key => $value){  
        if(strcasecmp($key[0],"t") != 0){
           echo  "O valor é: ".$value." e o índice é ".$key."<br/>";
        }
      }
?>
```

Se **$key** recebe o valor do ínidice que é o nome, logo **$key[0]** contém a primeira letra da palavra. Cientes disso, atribuímos ao segundo parâmetro da função a letra **T** e fazemos a comparação.  Se **$key[0]** for diferente da letra **T** imprimimos o nome do aluno, caso contrário ignoramos da impressão.

[image: Em funcionamento]

Comment: Rafael sua explicação foi TOP!!!. Estava justamente querendo entender com fazer tal comparação. Ajudou muito nos meus estudos. Grande abraço